# "-" in grep search pattern

Tags: php, regex, linux, command-line, grep

I use the following command to search all PHP files that contain "send"

```
 grep -rnw --include=\*.php -rnw '.' -e "send"
```

When I tried to do

```
 grep -rnw --include=\*.php -rnw '.' -e "->send"
```

it returns nothing, why is that?

```
 grep -rnw --include=\*.php -rnw '.' -e ">send"
```

This is good. Just can't have that "-" in the search pattern

Comment: In the future, consider building sufficiently standalone examples that folks can test the code given in your question without needing to create files on-disk, modify the code to read from a different source, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Source of the Problem

As @Charles Duffy pointed out, the source of the issue is `-w` option that causes Grep to select only those lines containing matches that form whole words (a "word" is considered as a sequence of letters, digits, and underscores). However, the real issue is *not just that `-` splits into words*, but the fact that

> The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or **preceded by a non-word constituent character**....
>   Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

So, for example, `$word->send()` will not match `->send` with `-w -e`, because the character preceding `-` is word constituent. But `$word->m()->send()` *will match*, because the `)` character is non-word constituent.

#### PHP Method Calls

Since you are parsing PHP files, the `->send` string represents a method call which means that the preceding sequence must be a *word-constituent* character optionally followed by spaces, or newlines:

```
$object->send();
$object->methodOne()->send();
$object
  ->methodOne()
  ->send();
```

The cases with space characters and parenthesis before `->send()` *will match* with `grep -w -e`. But the case where the preceding character is a letter, digit, or underscore (`$$object->send()`) *will not match* the pattern, because `-w` requires the preceding character to be *non-word constituent* character.

## Solutions

Thus, `-w` is not appropriate option for the patterns beginning with `-`, even with `-e`. But the issue occurs only when `-` is either at the beginning, or at the end of the pattern. You can simply escape it: `\-` and match non-word constituent character after `send`, i.e. `[^_[:alnum:]]`, or `\W` for the extended syntax:

```
grep '\->send[^_[:alnum:]]'
grep -E '\->send\W'
```

Personally, I prefer `grep '\->send *('` for searching for method calls, since the coding standards in our company do not allow to put the opening parenthesis of a method call to the lines next to the method name.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the right thing by using `-e` immediately preceding the data starting with a dash. The outstanding problem is the `-w` argument.

`grep -w` matches on words. `-` splits into two words. Thus, you can't use these things together.

```
$ echo 'foo->send' | grep -e '->send'
foo->send
$ echo 'foo->send' | grep -w -e '->send'
$
```

Instead of `-w`, consider only using `[[:>:]]` to match end-of-word, since your pattern can never occur at a beginning of a word:

```
$ echo 'foo->send' | grep -e '->send[[:>:]]'
foo->send
$ echo 'foo->sender' | grep -e '->send[[:>:]]'
$
```